# Issue while creating an App Package for Xamarin.UWP app in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, syncfusion, xamarin.uwp

When I try to release an UWP app made in Xamarin, I'm getting following error in release mode. Is there any solution for this issue?

ErrorNUTC1056:Internal Compiler Error: 0x8000ffff. Error encountered while compiling method

Comment: There are no enough information for you this issue, please provide a minimal simple reproducible sample?

Comment: Hi can you provide more information like what are the syncfusion controls you are using, also provide a minimal sample to reproduce the issue so that it will be helpful to investigate more on this.

Comment: I was using SfListView but not I have removed it from the project.

Comment: @Hetal So does your issue have been resolved after you remove it from your project?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT no it didn't fixed :(

Comment: @Hetal Could you provide a minimal sample to reproduce this issue?